# android: How to update badge TextView from a class that extends RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview

I am trying to update my badge based on click events of buttons inside a recycler view. this is my code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu);
        item = menu.findItem(R.id.add);
        badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        mCounter = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        cartButton=(Button) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        cartButton.setTypeface(icon);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

I want to update the value of mCounter which here:

This is the recyclerview code:

```
  holder.cartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               mCounter.setText("2");// THIS DOES NOT WORK

            }
        });
```

PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: Could you explain what happens with your current solution? Crash? Not updating?

Comment: @Shahid Sarwar you can also achieve it by making interface in adapter

Comment: not updating.. it doesnt crash.. just not doing anything

Answer (score 2):

You can perform this task in 4 ways :

1. Create `public static` variable and set its value to your badge TextView.
2. create `BroadcastReceiver` and call it when value changes.
3. Use `EventBus` [reference](http://androidgig.com/eventbus-library-in-android/)
4. Create an `interface`

Answer (score 1):

You should rather pass this event (or just the number You want to set) back to activity, invoke `invalidateOptionsMenu();` and in the function `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` invoke the code You have in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`